# Catch in Java a exception thrown in Scala - unreachable catch block

Tags: java, scala, exception, compiler-errors, scala-java-interop

Scala [doesn't have](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/177806) checked exceptions. However, when calling scala code from java, it's desirable to catch exceptions thrown by scala.

Scala:

```
def f()=
    {
    //do something that throws SomeException
    }
```

Java:

```
try
    { f() }
catch (SomeException e)
    {}
```

javac doesn't like this, and complains that "this exception is never thrown from the try statement body"

Is there a way to make scala declare that it throws a checked exception?

Comment: Please show your exact java code, because "try:" is not valid syntax.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Fixed it. Sorry about that, I'm used to python's syntax and too reliant on my IDE

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a `throws` annotation:

```
@throws(classOf[SomeException])
def f()= {
    //do something that throws SomeException
    }
```

You can also [annotate a class constructor](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/3388):

```
class MyClass @throws(classOf[SomeException]) (arg1: Int) {
}
```

This is [covered in the Tour of Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/106)

Comment: I think the annotation has to come before `def f()`.

Comment: @harpsealpup Indeed, I'm still experimenting with it. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 10):

You can still catch too many exceptions and then re-throw the ones you can't handle:

```
try { f(); }
catch (Exception e) {
  if (e instanceof SomeException)  // Logic
  else throw e;
}
```