# Getting exception is never thrown in the corresponding try block when moved from scala 2.12.4 to 2.12.18

Tags: java, scala

I have a method where a custom exception is thrown in a future. Caller code looks like below -

```
   try {
            Future<Option<type>> futureRet = doWork(input);
            Option<type> res = Await$.MODULE$.result(futureRet, Duration.apply("30s"));
        } catch (CustomException e) {
            return customExceptionHandler(e)
          }
          catch (Exception e) {
            return handleException(request, e);
        }
```

The method code where a future.failed() can be returned is as follows -

```
  override def doWork(
     input: String
  ): Future[Option[ReturnType]] = {
   if(!input.isEmpty)
      completeWork(input)
    } else {
      Future.failed(customExceptionHandler("bad input"))
    }
  }
```

Here is how CustomException is defined -

```
case class CustomException(er: String) extends Exception(s"error er")
```

Above code works perfectly fine with Scala 2.12.4 but it gives compilation error
with scala 2.12.18 with error "exception is never thrown in the corresponding try block".
Interestingly if i remove  catch (CustomException e) block and exception is thrown from doWork, its of type CustomException in debugger but still i get compilation error.
How may i fix it? What changed across the scala versions.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20006823/catch-in-java-a-exception-thrown-in-scala-unreachable-catch-block

Comment: It's weird that a Scala method throws while it returns `Future`. `Future` already encapsulates exceptions.

Comment: It's the `Await` that throws I believe.